# Search for movie atoms with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, quicktime

How to retrieve movie atoms from file with ffmpeg? For example I need `avcC` atom bytes. I would rather not code parser myself if there is some solution.

http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/mov_8c-source.html seems to provide some API, but I'm not familiar with ffmpeg.

Or is there direct API to obtain SPS and PPS NALs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if FFmpeg offers a direct API to retrieve these details. However, here's an incredibly lazy solution that should allow you to grab the `avcC` atom from a QuickTime/MP4 file:

1. Open the file and locate the `moov` atom in the top-level atom structure (traverse among `mdat`, `ftyp`, and perhaps a few other atoms).
2. Load the entire `moov` atom into memory (it will fit easily).
3. Perform a string search for 'avcC'.

It's not the cleanest approach but it will probably work. For extra sanity (just in case the string 'avcC' occurs elsewhere in the atom, like in a metadata atom), check the 4 bytes preceding the 'avcC' string, treat them as a big-endian 32-bit number which indicate the length of the `avcC` atom, and make sure that they make sense. I just checked a few H.264 .MP4 files and, empirically, the length is about 43-45 bytes. At the very least, make sure that the length of the atom is greater than 8 (minimum atom size) and also doesn't bump up against the end of the `moov` atom.